# Desktop PC, unplugged, hibernation, draining motherboard battery?

Tags: battery, hibernate, desktop-computer, poweroff

If I put my PC to hibernation and then unplug it, will it drain the motherboard battery? I've read a lot of posts, but this is one thing I haven't seen, because of laptop users. Does hibernation drain any power at all on Desktop PC?

Answer (score 7):

The motherboard battery is only used to preserve the real-time clock and CMOS settings. Hibernation saves your computer's state to the hard drive.

Comment: Yeah, the "drain" is exactly the same as it would be with the OS "shut down".

Answer (score 0):

If you've unplugged your desktop computer, you're no longer in "hibernate" mode... that thing is off. The motherboard battery only stores clock and CMOS settings, as other users have said, but it doesn't power any of the other components of your computer. It can't, even if it wanted to, so whether your computer is on, off, hibernating, plugged in or unplugged makes no real difference.

Comment: **Hibernation** stores the state to the **hard drive**, you must be confusing it with **sleep** mode. So no, unplugging a PC in *hibernation* mode will not invalidate its *hibernating* state.